# Какая форма слова правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Помогите разобраться, какую форму слова лучше и правильнее поставить в предложении ниже.

*Немногие в ней бывали, но те, кто хоть раз **испытывал/испытал** на себе здешнее гостеприимство, надолго задерживались...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При подлежащем – относительном местоимении **кто** (в функции союзного
> слова в придаточном предложении) сказуемое может стоять как в форме
> единственного, так и в форме множественного числа... Форма
> множественного числа, возможная при условии, что в главном предложении
> соотносительное слово и сказуемое тоже стоят во множественном числе,
> подчеркивает множественность производителей действия. Ср. разные формы
> согласованиям одном и том же сложном предложении: *Все, кто мог ехать,
> ехали сами собой; те, кто остановились, решали сами с собой, что им
> надо было делать (Л. Толстой).*

(Розенталь и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, М.: ЧеРо, 1999)
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_05 (см. §187, 2б)

В нашем случае возможны оба варианта, но вариант единственного числа мне кажется предпочтительным, поскольку речь не идет о *совместном* действии "задерживавшихся" (каждый в неопределенное время делал это сам). Возможен и вариант, позволяющий обойти необходимость компромиссного выбора (рассогласование по числу с местоимением "кто" или "те") :

> Немногие в ней бывали, но всякий, **кто** хоть раз испыт**ал** на себе здешнее
> гостеприимство, надолго задерживал**ся**...

**P.S.** Что касается выбора между такими формами того же "слова" из вопроса как *совершенный/несовершенный вид* глагола. В имеющемся контексте (получение опыта) глагол несовершенного вида мог бы обозначать неоднократное совершение действия (а не продолжающийся процесс его совершения), однако в предложении дополнительно содержится буквальное указание на *однократную* форму такого действия, которая обычно выражается глаголом совершенного вида ("*испытал* тамошнее гостеприимство"). Поэтому выбор -  пользу глагола совершенного вида. В этом предложении уместны только варианты "*(уже) испытывал*" (без "хоть раз"), либо "**хоть раз испытал**".

Comment: Да, пожалуй. Спасибо. Добавлю об этом менее типичном для такого предложения затруднении.

Comment: @Alex_ander, огромное спасибо за ответ.